# opencv_traincascade - reusing stageN file to improve cascade

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

As we know opencv_createcascade creates stage[0-(N-1)] files after each iteration of training algorithm, where N is a value of numStages parameter.

I've trained cascade.xml with 2 iterations (numStages 2). When my cascade was being trained opencv_createcascade created stage0 and stage1 files.

My question is: Can I reuse file stage1 to speed up training with greater numStages ??

Comment: yes you can, but I'm not sure whether you are allowed to change other parameters. But that won't use the .xml result, it will re-use the files created in the subfolder (intermediate training result files). So if you try to train 20 stages and and your pc crashes on stage 10 you can "resume" the same training with the same command (or higher number of stages) from those intermediate results. It will notify you, that stages 0 .. 9 are loaded.